# Learning C and trying to make program that finds all sums of squares but I can't figure out the last part

Tags: c

I'm creating a program that takes a number as input and the program finds the sums of squares, right now if I enter the number 5, it returns 4 + 1. The current program only displays solutions that are unique combinations of squares and I'm trying to get it to recognize and display all possible solutions.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()

{
  int i,j,number;
  printf("Enter a number: ");
  scanf("%d",&number);
  i=1;
  while (i*i <= number)
    {
      j=1;
      while (j<i)
        {
          if (i*i + j*j == number)
            printf("Found: %d + %d\n",i*i,j*j);
          j++;
        }
      i=i+1;
    }

  return (0);

}
```

Comment: There are no other squares that add up to 5. What result are you expecting instead?

Comment: Enter 65. You'll get 49+16 and 64+1.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2068122/natural-number-which-can-be-expressed-as-sum-of-two-perfect-squares-in-two-diffe for the math to find numbers that have more than 1 sum of squares solutions.

Comment: @Barmar that was a bad example, right now when I enter other numbers, for example 9, there is no output but it should output something like 4 + 4 + 1

Comment: You only have two variables `i` and `j`, so you only find sums of two squares, not any number of squares.

Comment: To do what you want you can use an array or recursion.

Comment: @Barmar "There are no other squares that add up to 5" --> (-2, 1), (-2, -1), (2, -1) are three other pairs. ;-)

Comment: Re [4 + 4 + 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59941056/learning-c-and-trying-to-make-program-that-finds-all-sums-of-squares-but-i-cant#comment106003203_59941056): "I'm trying to get it to recognize and display all possible solutions." --> If more than 2 squares can be added, then `1*1 + 1*1 + 1*1 + ...` will satisfy all positive `number`.

Comment: @Barmar I think that last comment of yours is an answer, because I do not think that an answer to this requires a complete code solution. Not the least because I suspect an (unusually well camouflaged) homework, i.e. according to the compromise https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions